# searchEntry() laravel or php constant fucntion?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

JS and laravel. I am wondering if this line is a constants function from laravel? What I'm trying to attain is to get a list of persons, but wondering if the "searchEntry(....)" is a constant function.

```
 $response = $entry->searchEntry(
        $region_id,
        $details['last_name'] ?? null,
        $details['first_name'] ?? null,
        $details['middle_name'] ?? null,
        $details['preferred_name'] ?? null,
        $details['nhi'] ?? null,
        null,
        $details['dob'] ?? null,
        isset($details['sex_id']) ? $sex[$details['sex_id']] : null,
        isset($details['gender_id']) ? $gender[$details['gender_id']] : null,
        isset($details['sexuality_id']) ? $sexuality[$details['sexuality_id']] : null
    );
```

Cheers for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

searchEntry() is not a standard inbuilt Laravel or PHP function. Rather it is a user defined function of the object $entry.  In the code above you should see where the $entry is instantiated from the Class, something like;

```
$entry= new SomeClass;
```

This will give you the user defined Class that formed the object $entry that contains the function searchEntry() so you can look in more detail at its implementation.

Ref: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php

Comment: Thank you so much for the enlightenment.